# Getting infinite loop after forking child

Tags: c

I am building a terminal in C , and i do not know why i get an infinite loop in reading from stream from file descriptor after forking a child

```
 void normal_excute(char** command, bool back){
   // intializing file descriptor
  int fds[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char buf[256];

  // opening pipes
  pipe(fds);
  // fork a child
  pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0) {
    // close read end for child
    close(fds[0]);
    // dupe write terminal with stdout
    dup2 (fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execv(command[0],command);
    exit(0);
  } else {
    // close read end for parent
    close(fds[1]);
    // opening stream on read end of pipe
    FILE* stream = fdopen(fds[0],"r") ;
    // reading from stream
    // infinite loop ------------------------------------------------
    while( fgets(buf,sizeof(buf) ,stream) !=NULL){}
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    close(fds[1]);
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
  } }
```

Comment: Is the child ever sending an `EOF`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know , so how to find out whether it send or not ? , i think it didn't send as i get in this infinite loop .

Comment: What command it is running?

Comment: it's running `ls` in a small content folder

Comment: Have you tried to print the `buff` in the loop to see what it is getting?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes , but unfortunately It stucks in fgets doesn't reach printing .

Comment: So it is not really an infinite loop... `fgets` can get stuck only if there is neither newline nor `EOF` was encountered.

Comment: @EugeneSh. while debugging more than one terminal were infinite looping in the back ground when i close all of them it get out of infinite loop , but buffer contain nothing

Comment: Out of interest. Have you tried to run the same without redirecting IOs, to see that your child is doing what you are expecting it to do?

Comment: execv() returns -1 , so there's problem command[0]="ls" , command[1]=0x0

Comment: Well. Now you see the importance of error handling...

Comment: aha `execvp` instead of `execv` to search for path in system solve it thanks @EugeneSh.